# enum pattern matching in Swift

Tags: swift, design-patterns, enums, matching

I just started learn Swift and trying to understand pattern matching.

I found the next example:

```
private enum Entities{
  case Operand(Double)
  case UnaryOperation(Double -> Double)
  case BinaryOperation((Double, Double) -> Double)
}
```

and later I use pattern matching to figure out the type of Entity

```
func evaluate(entity: Entities) -> Double? {
    switch entity{
    case .Operand(let operand):
        return operand;

    case .UnaryOperation(let operation):
        return operation(prevExtractedOperand1);

    case .BynaryOperation(let operation):
        return operation(prevExtractedOperand1, prevExtractedOperand2);
    }
}
```

Syntax of getting associated value seems little bit weird, but it works fine.

After that I found, that it is possible to use pattern matching in `if` statement, so I tried to do the same with `if`

```
if case entity = .Operand(let operand){
    return operand
}
```

but compiler throws error Expected ',' separator, which, I suspect, has nothing common with real reason of the error.

Could you pls help me to understand, what is wrong with my attempt to use pattern matching in `if` statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the syntax you want is this:

```
if case .Operand(let operand) = entity {
    return operand
}
```

or this:

```
if case let .Operand(operand) = entity {
    return operand
}
```

The variable to be bound needs to be to the left of the `=` sign in a `let`.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day. Now it makes perfect sense.